# UINavigationBar marquee in objective c Iphone

Tags: objective-c

Please, I want to display a message which move marquee into NavigationBar, like "welcome into my application which allowed you to search new customers". I use .xib for draw my interface.
I search a lot, but I don't find any help. can you help me please.

Comment: I want to display a message which move into NavigationBar, like marquee in css

Comment: I think following link will help you.

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762881/how-can-i-use-marquee-in-my-application>